# why sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features shows results that compatible with Standard edition?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have SQL Server 2016 Enterprise edition, I restored the DB's to SQL Server 2019 Enterprise edition.
But I want to check if I can restore it in SQL Server 2019 Standard.

if I run the DMV sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features in SQL Server 2019 Enterprise, the results that returns:
Compression,
Partitioning,
ColumnStoreIndex

which means I can't downgrade to standard edition.
but according to Microsoft documentation SQL Server 2019 Standard supports the these features.
so why these results appears in sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features?

Comment: Prior to SQL Server 2016 SP1 these features were indeed restricted to Enterprise and not available in Standard; the view likely was not changed for compatibility purposes, but at the same time this should not prevent you from restoring the database in 2019 Standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a note in the documentation that clearly states:

> Starting with SQL Server 2016 (13.x) Service Pack 1, these features, except `TransparentDataEncryption` are available across multiple SQL Server Editions, and not limited to Enterprise or Developer Editions only.

So the code you want is:

```sql
select *
from sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features
where feature_name = 'TransparentDataEncryption'
```

---

I think the docs are actually wrong still, because Change Data Capture is [not available in Express Edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/editions-and-components-of-sql-server-2022?view=sql-server-ver16#data-warehouse) or LocalDB. The DMV could certainly be made more useful by adding columns showing which edition supports these features, at least for the current version.

Comment: That documentation section is a bit weird. the DMV is documented under Azure SQL Database, but not under SQL Server. Also, the DMV returns an empty resultset as of SQL 2022 (including SQL Database) (TDE *is* available in SE as of SQL Server 2022).

Comment: @TiborKaraszi Do you actually have it enabled on that database? I get `Compression` `Partitioning` `ColumnStoreIndex` on my DB in SQL Server 2016

Comment: D'oh! No, I didn't have any "enterprise features" in that database. I have never been a fan of how this DMV works, btw. Anyhow, I'm on 2022, and it still returns for me Compression and Columnstore Index. So not even does it miss that TDE is now available in SE, it also report stuff that has been available in lower editions for 7 years, now. Anyhow, I have passed on that this isn't documented under the "SQL Server" section, we'll see if it is picked up.

Comment: So basically this DMV is useless? According to the documention these features supports SQL Server 2019 standard, and i won't have a problem to restore it there?

Comment: No, it tells you which of those documented features are enabled in the database (without having to query each separately). Whether it actually makes a difference to moving editions is dependent on versions. Certainly it could be made more useful, but it's not useless. TDE and CDC is still not supported on Express or LocalDB for example

Comment: Appreciate you answer. Thanks, so as the 3 results I got from the query I realize that it won't be issue restoring from Enterprise 2016 to Standard 2019, as those features are supporting SQL Server standard 2019. I Will check it. Thanks